# Convert a table record to jsonb and assign to a variable

Tags: jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am facing an error in converting a table record to jsonb and then assign it to a variable. I am getting the follwing error. I also tried with to_jsonb function and it too gave the same error.

**ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.**

Following is the code I am using. Table users has a lot of columns about 100. I hope this does not matter.

```
do
$$
declare
json_elements jsonb;
begin
    select json_elements = row_to_json(t)::jsonb from users t limit 1;
    select json_elements;
end;
$$
```

Note: I am using postgres 9.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as follows and it worked.

```
do
$$
declare
json_elements jsonb;
begin
    select row_to_json(t)::jsonb into json_elements from users t limit 1;
    raise notice '%s' json_elements;
end;
$$
```

The error was in the select statements. I am from SQL server background and i wanted to see the value by using the select. So I changed the first select to select into and the replaced the second one with raise notice. it started working.